# Uncover a weapon

Tags: word-usage

Looking for a word for "removing a cover from a weapon" in a sense of conflict escalation, like "I am ready to use something against you".

Comment: In Chinese we have an idiom that goes "swords unsheathed and bows drawn" which means exactly what you described, but I don't think it has the same connotations in English.

Comment: You usually ***draw*** the weapon from the cover, not the other way around. You could ***bare** your teeth* though, if it was going to be a no-holds-barred "bite your way to victory". That's the way most predators have to fight anyway, even if it seems gross to us.

Comment: *To draw a bow* means 'to pull back the string of a bow in order to fire an arrow from it'. [See the results of a Google Images search for "drawing a bow"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22drawing+a+bow%22&num=100&safe=off&rlz=1C1CHFX_enUS577US577&espv=2&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=TP-UVIPjMZKuyATW0YCYAw&ved=0CB8QsAQ&biw=1846&bih=952)

Comment: Uncovered, brought out, brought into view, unsheathed, showed him your holstered gun, unholstered, sooooooo many possibilities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Unsheathe](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/unsheathe):

> Draw or pull out (a knife, sword, or similar weapon) from its sheath or covering.

I'm not quite sure this fits your intended usage; it would be easier if you gave us an example sentence.

Answer (score 3):

One term that describes provocative military or diplomatic conduct that may lead to an escalation in tensions between two nations is *saber* (or *sabre*) *rattling*. [Merriam-Webster Online](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/saber%20rattling) defines the phrase rather narrowly:

> **saber rattling** (1922) ostentatious display of military power

But taken literally, it refers to rattling one's sword while leaving it in its scabbard. One can imagine that such behavior might be intended not as an empty threat but as a warning (if any were needed) that the saber in question has a metal blade and that it can be produced at a moment's notice.

If you think of a rattlesnake's tail rattling as being similar to saber rattling, you might suppose (by analogy to MW's definition of "saber rattling") that the action is nothing more than an ostentatious announcement that its bearer is an agitated and venomous snake. But to me it seems just as reasonable to interpret the rattling not as an exercise in bluster and bluff but as a calibrated escalation and formal warning: The snake will strike if the perceived threat advances any closer.

Because saber rattlers are human, their motives are more difficult to read than rattlesnakes' motives tend to be. But this ambiguity doesn't make the situation any less dangerous. With humans, there is always the possibility that what to one party is a Reproof Valiant is to the other party a Countercheck Quarrelsome, and so the parties may reach the [seventh cause](http://www.shakespeare-navigators.com/as_you_like_it/As_You_Like_It_Act_5_Scene_4.html) unseasonably early. A saber rattler may be bluffing, or he (or she) may be giving you one last chance to back off before drawing the weapon and demanding satisfaction.

Answer (score 2):

It is not clear to me how literal the scenario you're asking about is. But if you're talking about a *non-literal* or *intangible* "weapon", such as a devastating piece of news that can stun a political opponent into submission, then the following metaphors might be useful:

"The knives were drawn."

"The gloves came off."

"The claws are out."

"He showed his hand."

Note that the first three metaphors are highly combative in their implication, whereas the last actually uses a gambling analogy referring to a previously hidden strength (like an "ace") being revealed, giving the opposition serious pause.

Answer (score 0):

Not specific to a weapon but I think of the word "unveiled."  From [Oxford Dictionary Online](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/unveil?q=unveiled):

> Unviel: Remove a veil or covering from, especially uncover (a new monument or work of art) as part of a public ceremony: